# Export dynamically generated webbrowser control content to excel

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, export-to-excel

I have a windows application in which an html report is displayed using the webbrowser control. The content of webbrrowser control is generated dynamically and provided as below

```
 webbrowser1.DocumentText=htmlString;
```

Now I want to export the webbrowser control content to excel on clicking the "Export to Excel button".

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is to create an excel template. Than you can open this template edit it and save it to a different location . This sample snippet can help you.

```
        using System;
        using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var excelApplication = new Excel.Application { Visible = false, DisplayAlerts = false };
                Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(Filename: @"C:\temp\YourTemplate.xlsx");
                Excel.Worksheet targetedExcelSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1];
                Excel.Range ATrialRange = targetedExcelSheet.Range["F4", Type.Missing];
                ATrialRange.Value2 = "The values that you have parsed from your html string";
                excelWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename: @"C:\temp\YourNewlyGenerated.xlsx");
                excelWorkBook.Close();
                excelApplication.Quit();    
            }
        }
```

You can use html agility pack to parse your html.

Comment: i didn't get this line of the code snippet ATrialRange.Value2 = "The values that you have parsed from your html string";

Comment: my recommendation is manually parse your html string extract the values from your html. Write it to your excel sheet. I do not know any other way of exporting an excel sheet from your webbrowser control.

Comment: Just be really careful using the iterop stuff - ensure you clean up after yourself, handle exceptions, close files, etc, etc, as none of it is garbage collected.

Comment: Does excelApplication.Quit(); line not clean up the mess? Should I manually assign null to them?